# scenebuilder layer classnotfound

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, scenebuilder, gluon

I'm having problem. I used SceneBuilder and JavaFX. When I used layer in SceneBuilder and I tried to load it in java. I've got the error message below:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Projects/des_project2/target/classes/view/user/UserMainView.fxml
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2848)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2692)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2661)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at controller.UserController.<init>(UserController.java:26)
    at controller.MainController.<init>(MainController.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at window.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:18)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.layout.Layer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2916)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2905)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)
    ... 36 more
```

It says cause by: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.layout.Layer` and in my fxml file says it cannot resolve the Layer `com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.layout.Layer`.

Could you help me on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added the components of this library (com.gluonhq.charm.glisten) to your project path correctly?

Comment: @BoHalim No, I haven't. Isn't it library from JavaFx? If so, how can I add this library to the project path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use all the components included in the Container or Control panels from Scene Builder in any JavaFX project (as well as those in the other panels like Menu, Shapes, 3D, ...), since those are built-in JavaFX components.

But those included in the `Gluon Mobile` panel are not regular JavaFX components.

[image]

These components are included in the Gluon Mobile [library](http://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/), and you can make use of it in your project as well, providing you include the proper dependencies.

The best way to do it is using the Gluon IDE [plugin](http://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/trynow/) on your favorite IDE (NetBeans, IntelliJ or Eclipse). Install the plugin and create a new project, it will include the Gluon Mobile dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.3.0'
}
```

You can select the Gluon Mobile - MultiView with FXML or Glisten-Afterburner templates. Both make use of FXML, and you can use Scene Builder 8.3.0 to design the Views for your project.

Note that you will be able to run this project on desktop and also on mobile (Android and iOS), using the same codebase.

Be aware that the library is not free, but you can fully explore it without a license.

Comment: I've got it now. Thank you very much :d